# Are targets appended?

Tags: cmake

I'm not entirely clear if calling, for instance, `target_link_libraries()` more than once for the same target will append the target's dependencies. For example, can I add options for the target `main` as follows?

```
option(ASSERT "Evaluate assertions" ON)

find_package(MyLib REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE MyLib::MyLib)

if (ASSERT)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE MyLib::enable_assert)
endif()
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely supported.

Comment: The answer to the body of your question is yes, you can do that. But I am not sure what do you mean about the question title. Targets appended to what? If you mean that imported targets are appended to the main target with each target_link_libraries() invocation, the answer is yes again. I guess that you are asking because you have found a problem somewhere. Maybe you could ask about it directly?

Comment: @Pedro Thanks! Your interpretation is correct: appending the main target. No, no problems at all, just a doubt and I wanted to make sure that I understood correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, from the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) documentation:

> Repeated calls for the same `<target>` append items in the order called.

So in your example, this:

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE MyLib::MyLib)
...
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE MyLib::enable_assert)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE MyLib::MyLib MyLib::enable_assert)
```

---

If you are using a simple boolean check to determine whether or not to include `MyLib::enable_assert` as an argument, you can use a [conditional generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#conditional-expressions) instead to simplify this logic:

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE 
    MyLib::MyLib 
    $<IF:$<BOOL:${ASSERT}>, MyLib::enable_assert, > 
)
```